# Confidence regions from a Gamma distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, confidence-interval, gamma-distribution

Let a random variable with posterior distribution be given by $X \sim \textrm{Gamma}(10,12)$. This is the result of Jeffreys prior $\pi_J(\lambda)$ multiplied by the Likelihood of i.i.d. $X_1,...,X_n \sim \textrm{Exp}(\lambda)$.

Also, $n=10$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i = 12$.

I'm trying to compute a one-sided Bayesian confidence region with level $0.05$ that takes the form $[\alpha,\infty)$, i.e. finding $\alpha$ such that $P(X≥a)=0.95$. This is what I have so far,

$$P(X≥a)=Q(10,\alpha/12) \Rightarrow 12Q^{-1}(10,19/12) \approx 65.1049$$

Where $Q$ is the regularized incomplete gamma function.

The value seems very high to me! Is this actually correct?

This is actually no the part I'm struggling with. I can't manage to compute a one-sided Bayesian confidence region with level $0.05$ that takes the form $(0,b)$, i.e. finding $\alpha$ such that $P(0<X<b)=0.95$. I don't know how to express this as a regularized incomplete gamma function nor inverse cumulative distribution function. If I run some python code, the program eventually fails since it's dealing with both $b$ and $\exp(b)$ which are conflicting and cannot be solved for simultaneously.

Can someone please help me compute $b$?

Comment: By "Bayesian confidence region" do you instead intend a credible interval? ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval

Comment: I'm new to this @Glen_b that's what the problem says.. All I'm trying to do is satisfying the probabilities by getting $a$ and $b$ correspondingly.

Comment: Btw, please ignore the value for $a$ it's way too high; I figured that there are two definitions and the one I'm using should use the inverse value $\beta$. Also, I managed to find $b$ the hard way, basically try and error.. I still don't know how to properly compute it via some formula.

Comment: Then (in relation to the use of 'confidence') it seems the error is not yours but someone else's. That now raises another question. Is this coursework (or other self-study)? If so, please see the self-study tag wiki info ...  https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: I'm an autodidact @Glen_b and am trying to improve my skills. I download books, read online and watch youtube tutorials. It's still a long way to go but I'm learning something new everyday at my own pace. There's also tons of content on GitHub :)

Comment: I guess that would be the epitome of self-study then. Where did you find such a question?

Comment: Any feedback on how to formally compute $b$ @Glen_b ?

Comment: If I am ready to give an answer, rest assured you will have it. It's not like I am waiting to be prompted in order to begin answering the question. I want to be sure I am clear what is being asked. It would help if you would clarify which parameterization you're using. Can you clarify what $\alpha$ is in $P(X≥a)=Q(10,\alpha/12)$ and where $a$ went?

Comment: My bad @Glen_b I meant no disrespect. Just curious, that's all.

Comment: Instead of $(10,\alpha/12)$ @Glen_b it should actually be $(10,12\alpha)$. That value seems more plausible and rather correct to me. And that's what I meant with inverse $\beta$ instead of $12$ it should be $1/12$. But it really depends on your [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) it's a matter of scaling.

Comment: I understand that it depends on the parameterization which is why I ask. The document you're looking at presumably defines what it means by X∼Gamma(10,12) *somewhere*. I presume it's either the shape-scale or shape-rate parameterization (but it might be something else -- e.g.  if a GLM was being used)

Comment: @Glen_b it's bayesian estimation not linear regression. It starts with i.i.d. $X_1,...,X_n \sim Exp(\lambda)$ and I had to come up with $X∼Gamma(10,1/12)$ after computing Jeffreys prior and so on.

Comment: I mentioned nothing about linear regression but you can certainly have a Bayesian question about linear regression (or indeed a GLM which I did mention). Thanks for attempting to clarify but we're still not closer to being able to tell what parameterization you're using for the gamma. Clearly $n=10$, but how did the $12$ come about? How does $\lambda$ relate to $12$ (or $1/12$)? Yet again, what is $\alpha$ in your question? Please clarify in your question.

Comment: Also, how did the 19 come about?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. Yes, $n=10$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i = 12$

Comment: Thanks, that helps! This information should be added to your question.

Comment: @Glen_b the expectation should also be $\alpha / \beta$

Comment: Please add any info provided in the comments in the question body. Also as Glen_b said, please add the [tag:self-study] tag.

Comment: Done @User1865345 :)

Comment: Thanks, I think it's now clear what $\alpha$ is in your question and which parameterization you're using.

Comment: What is still unclear is what parameter we're producing an interval for. It's not $X$, presumably, since you're using $X$ to represent the random variables for which the realizations are your *data* and it wouldn't do to use $X$ for both of those things.  Are you instead producing an interval for $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, $\lambda$ instead of $x$; i.e. support $\lambda∈(0,\infty)$

Comment: Please adjust the question to reflect this. In the comments you mentioned a Jeffrey's prior but there's no evidence of a prior in your question (and indeed it seems like there can only have been a flat prior with the numbers you mention. Was that what you were supposed to use here? Also, I'd still like clarification of where the 19 came from. (I hope you can understand why I did not immediately attempt to answer what was posted! I feel we are getting much closer to a clear question now, only a few more things to clear up)

Comment: I added more context as per you request @Glen_b but, honestly, I have no clue where the 19 came from it's what wolfram alpha does went inverting $Q$ the regularized incomplete gamma function and as far as I know it's correct.

Comment: 19 is the odds for being in the interval to outside it. I presume that came into it somehow.

Comment: My apologies; now that I understand the question properly, I can see that the Jeffrey's prior is in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're using the shape-rate parameterization of the gamma. Presumably also $\lambda$ is the rate parameter of the exponential. These will be taken as given for what follows.

Let $\underline{x} = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ be the observed values of $X_1,...,X_n\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}\text{Exp}(\lambda)$. Abusing notation a little, and noting that the Jeffrey's prior for the exponential parameter is  $\propto 1/\lambda$ on the positive half line (an improper prior), we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{\lambda|\underline{X}=\underline{x}} &\propto&  f_{\underline{X}|\lambda}(\underline{x}) \cdot f_\lambda\\
& \propto & \left[\prod_i \lambda e^{-\lambda x_i}\right]\cdot \lambda^{-1} \: I_{(0,\infty)}\\
& = & \lambda^{n-1} e^{-\lambda\sum_i x_i} \:  I_{(0,\infty)} 
\end{eqnarray*}

which we can recognize as the kernel of a $\text{Gamma}(n,\sum_i x_i)$ in the shape-rate parameterization. This much you already knew (though there were multiple issues with the way you were writing it that were causing me some confusion).

Now, a 95% credible interval for $\lambda$ of the form $[a,\infty)$ (again, abusing notation) puts $a$ at the 5th percentile of the distribution. If you have the inverse gamma cdf function, this is simple; with $n=10$ and $\sum_i x_i=12$ you get the value $a\approx 0.4521$ (in R this is `qgamma(.05,10,12)`). This value makes sense.

(The value $65.1$ you had came from using the wrong parameterization)

With the usual (lower) regularized incomplete gamma, you have to find $a$ such that

$P(as,n)=0.05$

Assuming by $Q$ you are looking at the *upper* rather than the *lower* regularized incomplete gamma, as with the notation here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables

and equivalently the upper regularized gamma here

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html

you'd instead be solving $Q(as,n)=0.95$. That is, finding $a$ such that $Q(12a,10) = 0.95$. This should give the $0.452$-ish value above.

For the other tail, you'd solve $Q(12b,10) = 0.05$

From the values you give, it's not quite clear to me how your inverse function $Q^{-1}$ is set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Glen_b. I'm getting 0.468307637002674 when solving for $b$ in $(12,10)=0.05$. This is wrong. Any idea why?

Comment: It looks like your Q function's arguments are not in the same order as the definition I used from the links that I gave. Swap them to match the reversed order in your function. You may also need to pay attention to the exact way the Q-function is defined to make sure it is definitely the upper regularized incomplete gamma.

Comment: The answer should be roughly 1.3, I think

Comment: Yes, that's the correct answer I've got mine accurate to 3dp. The only problem is that the regularized incomplete gamma function returns a univariate polynomial of degree $9$ in terms of $b$ multiplied by $e^{-12b}$ which only wolfram alpha can solve. My python program still breaks as it isn't able to solve such complex equations which, to be honest, really sucks. I'm considering switching to R instead.

Comment: wouldn't `scipy.stats.gamma.ppf` do what you need in python?

Comment: Yes, you have a valid point @Glen_b . This module actually uses the right scaling I  was looking for all along, thanks!